# @feathersjs/client @feathersjs/socketio-client build fail

Tags: ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, feathersjs

Used create-react-app.  added the client and socketio-client.

dev server runs fine.

go to build :

> Failed to minify the code from this file:
>
> ```
>     ./node_modules/@feathersjs/socketio-client/lib/index.js:10
> ```

thought I must've messed something up.  so download the basic feathers chat react client example.  dev server runs fine. go to build :

> static/js/main.b9a07b83.js from UglifyJs SyntaxError: Unexpected token
>   punc «,», expected punc «:»
>   [./~/@feathersjs/commons/lib/commons.js:6,49]
>
> error Command failed with exit code 1.

I thought the client js files in the feathers library were written to be ES5 browser compatible/buildable w/ create-react-app.  but for some reason, during build they are throwing these errors.

I have no clue how to fix this without having to eject webpack config (from react-scripts) include es2015 preloader.

Is there an easier way?  I must have something configured incorrectly, bc the basic feathers/react chat example isn't even building...

**Reproduce:**

- git clone https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-chat-react
- yarn install
- yarn build

Comment: workaround:  add library cdn to index.html, remove from build packages
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/socket.io-client@1.7.3/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@^3.0.0/dist/feathers.js"></script>

in react app:
const socket = io(CONNECTION_URL);
const client = window.feathers().configure(window.feathers.socketio(socket));

Answer (score 0):

It was a mistake in the example application. As [documented in the usage with create-react-app](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html#create-react-app) anything that needs a pre-transpiled version should [use @feathersjs/client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html#feathersjsclient).

It is now fixed in the [feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-chat-react](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-chat-react) repository (with [this commit](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-chat-react/commit/4329523c8377b52debb2c76b09e52a4a2dfd13e1)).